# nothing to do but <wait> <to wait> <waiting>

Tags: word-choice

I've come up with this sentence:
"There's nothing to do but wait until they get here"

And I'm not sure about that wait.

1. Does it need to in front of itself?
2. Doesn't waiting also seem like a good option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular infinitive or bare infinitive after but?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/101947/regular-infinitive-or-bare-infinitive-after-but) See also [There's nothing to do but do/to do something](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/88123/theres-nothing-to-do-but-do-to-do-something)